# How to set Position of a Dialog to where user clicks on the MapView?

Tags: google-maps, android-layout, android-widget, android

I'm using google maps MapView in my project. I need to create a Dialog like google map when user user clicks at a particular Marker on the map and I need to position that Dialog where user clicked(inside viewport). 
How can I set position of a Dialog to where user clicks on the Map?
I've seen API of Dialog to set it's position to some coordinate but don't know how to get coordinate of the point where user clicks.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Register the map click handler.

```
// Capture map click event.
google.maps.event.addListener(YourMap 'click', $.proxy(this.mapClickHandler, this));
```

In the function you'll get the event object back. From this you can retrieve the lat and long of the mouse click. If you have a marker you can then use those values to set its position on the map.

```
mapClickHandler = function (event)
{
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng())
    // Main Marker. Or in your case a google maps dialogue.
    this.marker.setPosition(position);
}
```

It occurred to me you might need the x,y screen coordinates, i'm not sure about that, i avoided using them as much as possible, though they might be available as properties in the event object also.

Found an example of using getProjection() that helps with getting screen position coordinates. However my example relied on extending googles OverlayView. I'm not sure if theres a way to get the projection from the map itself. Would have to look that up.

```
MyOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
var point = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(event.latLng);
point.x;
point.y;
```

Comment: Note, that you could probably shorten that to setPosition(event.latLng)

Answer (score 1):

make class MarkerPopup which is layout to be shown at that point and then on onTap method done like that

```
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    MyOverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
    MarkerPopup this.popup = new MarkerPopup(mapView);
    MapView.LayoutParams params = new MapView.LayoutParams(
            MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // width
            MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // height
            item.getPoint(), MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    params.mode = MapView.LayoutParams.MODE_MAP;
    this.mapView.addView(popup, params);


    // change parameter
    popup.setLayoutParams(params);
    // visibility
    popup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Actually I've created a CustomItemizedOverlay extending ItemizedOverlay and using onTap method to show that Dialog. I can't get and set LayouParams of MapView in CustomizedOverlay class as I can't call MapView.LayoutParams in onTap method.

Comment: How can I set position of popup to user click by using MapView.LayoutParams by the way?

Comment: Sorry for mistake. it will be on ontap method.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is sample Code for android drag-drop pin on mapview [See This](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid)**

Comment: Code is frankly too big. Can you specify where is the code for positioning of dialog to click location?